# Optimizing order by with a limit in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a 3 million records table called "transactions" .

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  lookupAId int(6) NOT NULL,
  .....
  updateDate TIMESTAMP
)
```

In the worst case the user will specify no filters and the query would looks like this :

```
select * from transactions
   join lookupA on (well indexed columns) 
   .. ( 12 lookup table joins) 
order by updateDate limit 500
```

Without the **order by** clause the query runs in milliseconds, but with the **order by** it takes about a minute. The table is projected to grow to 12-15 million records.

1. My SLA is to get results in under a second, is it possible in MySql ?
2. How can I optimize the order by clause to make this perform.

I run MySql 5.7 in xLarge memory optimized RDS instance in AWS

**UPDATE 1** updateDate  has a time component and is indexed (B-tree, non-unique)

**Update 2** This worked , although I don't know why

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from transactions order by updateDate) transactions
   join lookupA on (well indexed columns) 
   .. ( 12 lookup table joins) 
   limit 500
```

Comment: Does updateDate have a time component? Have you tried adding an index for updateDate?

Comment: Are you retrieving **all** columns from the related tables, or just a few ones? You could use a covering index to avoid the "secondary index lookup" that MySQL suffers from.

Comment: You don't say but I assume `updateDate` belongs to the table `transactions`. Is it so?

Comment: Those are fk lookups , only one row per lookup table

Comment: updateDate belongs to transactions, correct

Comment: Have you tried running the query without the joins? `select * from transactions order by updateDate limit 500`? Is it fast?

Comment: I only get performance degradation when I sort , it is very snappy otherwise

Comment: @JavaHead Have you run the query on transactions only without any joins? That exact query that I quoted?

Comment: @trognanders  without any joins it is also very fast

Comment: @JavaHead Then it's the join lookups that are making it slow. What columns do you need from each table? Put all the rows in a "covering index"; that will make the query faster.

Comment: If you include the execution plan of the `ORDER BY` I'll upvote your question.

Comment: Thanks Impaler and Trognanders , I'll check out "covering index"

Comment: This is not a deficiency in the Optimizer.  The query has no way of knowing which 500 rows you will need until it has run through all the `JOINs`.  One JOIN may eliminate all rows.  Or it may produce a thousand rows.  And it cannot tell which `updateDate` value will survive the JOINs.

Comment: How big is `transactions`?  If it is really huge, then it may have to hit the disk 500 times to get just the rows from it!  This will push against your SLA.  A UI with 500 rows is (often) excessive; do you really need 500?

Comment: Are any `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns involved?  They add to the disk-hit count.  UUIDs are also a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is probably doing a lot of work on the query before limiting the query size with limit. This seems to be a known weakness of MySQL.

Try doing the select from transactions in a subquery to limit the result set size before doing the joins.

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from transactions order by updateDate limit 500) transactions
   join lookupA on (well indexed columns) 
   .. ( 12 lookup table joins)
```

Comment: That worked in under a second, i didn't even have to limit to 500 in subquery , just ordering and keeping the limit at the bottom .

Comment: I guess it has to do with the subpar SQL optimizer that MySQL has.

Comment: @JavaHead I think it is definitely a quirk of the query optimizer. MySQL has a statement `EXPLAIN` that will show what strategy the database is using. If moving limit out of the subquery maintains equal performance I suspect that you will find it just forced the engine to use the index on updateDate. Otherwise it might be that the optimizer was doing all of the joins and stuff before applying the limit.

Comment: That may lead to fewer than 500 rows.  Or more than 500.  This is because the `JOINs` may get 0 or multiple rows.

Comment: @RickJames That is a really good point. Would it be better to use a `left join`? It is presumably still faster because no row sources are involved which have the same magnitude as `transactions`?

Comment: @trognanders - `LEFT JOIN` will never drop to 0, but it can expand to more than 1.  Anyway, it is semantically _not_ the same (except in some cases).  "the same magnitude as transactions" -- what is this statement based on?

Comment: @trognanders - I discuss that a bit further in my second Answer.  (I decided to do 2 Answers since they are radically different, and apply to different situations.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have it, the `ORDER BY` would definitively benefit from the index:

```
create index ix1 on transactions (updateDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique for tackling this problem:

```
SELECT ... JOIN ...
    LIMIT ...
```

is to:

1. Do the minimal amount of work to find the `PRIMARY KEY` values of the rows that factor into the `LIMIT` rows.
2. Feed those ids into the `JOINs` to get the rest of the info.

As your query stands, the Optimizer throws up its hands and simply does all the `JOIN` (optimizing each as best it can), generating a large (many rows, many columns) intermediate table, then apply the `ORDER BY` (sort the many rows of many columns) and `LIMIT` (deliver some of those rows).

With `INDEX(OrderDate)` (and that column is in the table it chooses to start the `JOINing` with) the Optimizer can at least consider using the index.  But that might be the worst case -- What if there are not 500 rows to be had; it will have done all the work anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The Optimizer does not know that a table is a simple "lookup" table.  It must be prepared to find 0 rows or more than 1 row.

Case 1:  You *know* that there is exactly 1 row in each of the lookup (`JOINed`) tables:

Case 2:  You *know* that there is at most 1 row in each lookup table.

In both of these cases, the following is an efficient way to rewrite the query:

```
SELECT  t.a, t.b, ...
        ( SELECT name FROM LU1 WHERE id = t.name_id ) AS name, 
        ( SELECT foo  FROM LU1 WHERE id = t.foo_id ) AS foo, 
        ...
    FROM transactions AS t
    ORDER BY t.OrderDate
    LIMIT ...
```

*and*

```
INDEX(OrderDate)
INDEX(id)  -- for each LU table, unless there is already `PRIMARY KEY(id)`
```

This formulation of the query will focus on walking through exactly 500 rows, presorted by `OrderDate`, looking up 12 things for each row.

It is semantically equivalent to Case 2 (`LEFT JOIN`) since it gives `NULL` for `name` (etc) when there is no mapping.

Technically, Case 1 is not the same.  If a lookup fails, `JOIN` will fail to count the row, but my reformulation will keep the row, showing `NULL`.